# Can't get div inner HTML on jQuery ready function

Tags: jquery, dom, innerhtml

I have some code on my page like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//code

});
```

And on jQuery ready, there is a code to get a div inner HTML:

```
var tmp = document.getElementById("content").InnerHTML;
```

It returns undefined. As I know jQuery ready runs when page HTML is completely loaded. But it can't just find div!

jQuery including and div id are correct.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var tmp = document.getElementById("content").InnerHTML;
```

This would work, except InnerHTML is not a property of HTMLElement. You simply misspelt innerHTML.

Try

```
                                             v

var tmp = document.getElementById("content").innerHTML;

                                             ^
```

Comment: Nice touch with the arrows.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using jQuery already, why not use it to find your DOM element? Assuming your div has an ID of "content":

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $tmp = $("#content"),
      html = $tmp.html();
});
```

Comment: On line 2, replace the semicolon at the end with a comma.

Comment: Thanks for admonition.

Comment: @roberthofer Wasn't meant as an admonition. Simply saying that jQuery will give you a lot of additional tools for manipulating the element. Certainly using vanilla JS is quicker if you only need to get that element's inner HTML. But caching the jQuery object for the element is pretty quick, and then you have access to all of the additional methods (binding events, et al).